# Dispatcher Invoke does not execute when using a lambda expression

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, lambda, dispatcher

Im not too experienced with the dispatcher, but I thought I had it worked out.

However now Im seeing something I really don't understand and figured I should ask here if someone could explain because its getting extremely frustrating.

Im trying to update the maximum value of my progressbar in my WPF window from another thread. 
So I use the Dispatcher to invoke the method.

This is my code:

```
_progressBarDialog.ProgressBar1.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action<int>((x)=>
{
   _progressBarDialog.ProgressBar1.IsIndeterminate = false;
      if (_progressBarDialog.ProgressBar1.Value > x)
          _progressBarDialog.ProgressBar1.Value = x;
      _progressBarDialog.ProgressBar1.Maximum = x;
}),DispatcherPriority.Send,max);
```

The problem is that it works sometimes and sometimes the program just halts. I know that the Invoke method is executed synchronously so the main thread pauses while its being invoked and that if I use BeginInvoke the main thread can continue, but the fact real problem is that the dispatcher never executes the code and thats why everything halts. If I use BeginInvoke I will get problems later on when I try to set the progressbar to a value that is larger than the maximum.

I've tried different dispatcher priorities.
I have a feeling that something is up with my parameter, but i really cant understand what.

Any help greatly appreciated, because I'm going out of my mind!

Edit: for some reason after I fiddled with DispatcherPriority everthing started working. 
I am even back to ivoking the dispatcher without that argument and it still works. 
Any ideas why this could be happening are still very welcome since I dont know why it works now and not before and this makes me feel that the code is realy unreliable.

Comment: Try it with
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(Action);
You should not push dispatcher frames with the Send Priority. That could cause real imported messages to be not Delivered

Comment: Thanks, but I believe that is a dangerous thing to do since I have more than one open WPF window in that application.

Comment: No it is not. If you are dealing with only one Application, No matter how mutch windows this App contains, there is only one Dispatcher that is allowed to "process" items on for that app. If you now call it this way you maybe get another Dispatcher, what is actually possible.
Every invoke back from an other Thread should be done with the Dispatcher you get from the Application.

Example from one of my gitHub projc:
https://github.com/JPVenson/WPFCommon/blob/master/JPB.WPFBase/MVVM/ViewModel/ThreadSaveViewModelActor.cs

Comment: My Application.Current is null. But the progressbar i showing. 
Im sure the window has initialized.